# How to move forked repo back to the main repo?

Tags: git, git-fork

I wrote a plugin, on git and it was forked by someone else and made better, with additional stuff, how can I bring the forked stuff to my repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your original repository. Then add a new remote say, `forked` with the clone URL of forked repository. Then Pull the changes from forked repository into your origin repository. Now you can Push the changes to remote `master` or another branch.

```
$ git remote add forked <forked-repo-url>

$ git checkout master
$ git pull forked master    # now your repo's master = forked repo's master

$ git push origin master    # push/update remote master
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a remote pointing to the other developer repo, fetch from it and then have fun merging/rebasing/cherry-picking on your own branches.